# How do i move a div box to center using css flex

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

[image]I am wanting to use flex to move this div box around but can't seem to move it. I don't want to use top, bottom, left and right.

I am trying to move the "shop-now-btn" below the heading. there is a grid above it and they seem to be joined when I try and move the "shop-now-btn".

```css
    .section-1{
   z-index: 100;
       background-image: url("https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/white_gywan_2400x.jpg?v=1551770466&auto=format&q=50&");
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       padding-left: 30px;
       padding-right: 30px;
       padding-top: 30px;
       animation: slideBg 10s ease-in-out 3s ;
       animation-timing-function: ease-in-out 3s;



}

@keyframes slideBg  {
   0% {
      background-image:url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/white_gywan_2400x.jpg?v=1551770466&auto=format&q=50&)
   }

   33% {
      background-image:url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/swatch-hero_2400x.jpg?v=1558564563&auto=format&q=50&)
   }

   100% {
      background-image:url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/last-slide_2400x.jpg?v=1551770643&auto=format&q=50&)
   }
}

.heading{
   font-size: 80px;
   position: relative;
   top: 45%;
   text-align: center;
}
.shop-now-btn{
   display: flexbox;
   font-size: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid #bfc5c7;
      max-height: 200px;
      max-width: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;


}
 .navgrid {
   
   transform: translate(0px, -130px);
    display: grid; 
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #bfc5c7;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
     
     <div class="heading">Bring Swallowtail Home
     </div>
     <div class="shop-now-btn">Shop Now</div>
     <div class="navgrid">
        <div id="item-0">
           <div class="logo">
              <svg height="39px" viewbox="0 0 107 39" width="107px">
                 <path </path>
              </svg>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item-1"><a href="/"><h1 class="background"><br>..................WholeSale<br>..................Steep </h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-2"><a href="/"><h1 class="tea_link">teas</h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-3"><a href="/"><h1 class="merch_link">merch</h1></a> </div>
        <div id="item-4"><a href="/"><h1 class="brew_link">brew wares</h1></a> </div>
        <div id="item-5"><a href="/"><h1 class="about_link">about us</h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-6"><a href="/"><h1 class="cart_link">cart</h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-7"><a href="/"><h1 class="wholesale_link">wholesale</h1></a></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

iv added all the code for the CSS but note that you can not render it all

Comment: flex settings need to be applied to a *container* , not to the element you want to center or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Putting a margin:0 auto will center your box. Let me know if this is what you mean.

```css
.section-1{
   z-index: 100;
       background-image: url("https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/white_gywan_2400x.jpg?v=1551770466&auto=format&q=50&");
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       padding-left: 30px;
       padding-right: 30px;
       padding-top: 30px;
       animation: slideBg 10s ease-in-out 3s ;
       animation-timing-function: ease-in-out 3s;
       background-size:cover;



}

@keyframes slideBg  {
   0% {
      background-image:url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/white_gywan_2400x.jpg?v=1551770466&auto=format&q=50&)
   }

   33% {
      background-image:url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/swatch-hero_2400x.jpg?v=1558564563&auto=format&q=50&)
   }

   100% {
      background-image:url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/last-slide_2400x.jpg?v=1551770643&auto=format&q=50&)
   }
}

.heading{
   font-size: 80px;
   position: relative;
   top: 45%;
   text-align: center;
}
.shop-now-btn{
      display: flexbox;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid #bfc5c7;
      max-height: 200px;
      max-width: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      position:relative;


}
  .navgrid {
   
   transform: translate(0px, -130px);
    display: grid; 
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #bfc5c7;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  <div class="navgrid">
        <div id="item-0">
           <div class="logo">
              <svg height="39px" viewbox="0 0 107 39" width="107px">
                 <path> </path>
              </svg>
           </div>
        </div>
       <div id="item-1"><a href="/"><h1 class="background"><br>  
       ......WholeSale<br>.......Steep </h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-2"><a href="/"><h1 class="tea_link">teas</h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-3"><a href="/"><h1 class="merch_link">merch</h1></a> </div>
        <div id="item-4"><a href="/"><h1 class="brew_link">brew wares</h1></a> </div>
        <div id="item-5"><a href="/"><h1 class="about_link">about us</h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-6"><a href="/"><h1 class="cart_link">cart</h1></a></div>
        <div id="item-7"><a href="/"><h1 class="wholesale_link">wholesale</h1></a></div>
 </div>
     
     <div class="heading">Bring Swallowtail Home
       <div class="shop-now-btn">Shop Now</div>
     </div>
     
     
    
       
</div>
```

Comment: yes, that works thanks but then how would you move it on the y axis?

Comment: you mean you want to rotate it?

Comment: @TJMC9010 you mean like that?? I edited the code. Let me know

Comment: edited the question and code

Comment: @TJMC9010 so your mean you want to put it below your header like the one in the picture??

Comment: yes I am wanting to but the shop now div below the "Bring swallowtail home" and leave the grip (navgrid) where it is

Comment: @TJMC9010 I edited the code. you can arrange your html inside the section1 div. put your flex boxes above the shop now button that should do it. separate the bring shwallowtail and put it down.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Let em try to edit it. I dont have all your css. if you can add it will be able to arrange that for you.

Comment: The css was added

Comment: Ok let me try to rearrange it for you.So you want exactly like the picture above is that right??

Comment: the first image is show i want it the second is what it looks like now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244452/discussion-between-crystal-and-tjmc9010).

Answer (score 0):

Display flex, align items and justify content are flex properties defined on the flex parent, not its children:

```css
.shop-now-btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: GT Pressura Mono, Roboto Mono, monospace;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #bfc5c7;
  max-height: 45px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.section-1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 100;
  background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/white_gywan_2400x.jpg?v=1551770466&auto=format&q=50&);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  animation: slideBg 10s ease-in-out 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  <div class="heading">Bring Swallowtail Home
  </div>
  <div class="shop-now-btn">Shop Now</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example with better defaults and less code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.shop-now-btn {
  font-size: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: GT Pressura Mono, Roboto Mono, monospace;
  border: 2px solid #bfc5c7;
  max-height: 45px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.section-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/white_gywan_2400x.jpg?v=1551770466&auto=format&q=50&);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  animation: slideBg 10s ease-in-out 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  <div class="heading">Bring Swallowtail Home
  </div>
  <div class="shop-now-btn">Shop Now</div>
</div>
```